# Change the shadow color of the DropdownButton menu

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it possible to change the shadow color of the DropdownButton menu?

[image: DropdownButton menu]

Comment: You need to create a custom widget for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the drop-down button with a container and add shadow to it. Make the elevation of drop-down button to 0

Answer (score 0):

add decoration for dropdownButton and set color for shadow
this the example:

```
decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.white,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
      topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
        topRight: Radius.circular(10),
        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
        bottomRight: Radius.circular(10)
    ),
    boxShadow: [
      BoxShadow(
        color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
        spreadRadius: 5,
        blurRadius: 7,
        offset: Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

Comment: BoxDecoration doesn't work on dropdown menu (only dropdown button)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **dropdown_button2** package

https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_button2